# Saving session on ajax post, and retrieving it on back button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have a page with search results and a filter bar.  When the filters are changed, it does an ajax post, which saves the filters to session and returns a partial view with the filtered results.

In the view, I pull the filters from session and use a htmlhelper extension to convert the session object to JSON.  I then bind the JSON to the populate the selected filters.

My problem occurs when the back button is hit.  The updated filters in session never get sent to the htmlhelper routine, and the filters are lost until a postback occurs.

Has anyone every encountered this issue?  I've tried the no-cache meta tag, but it doesn't seem to affect it.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried all variations of meta no-cache tags, but in the end, I used an ajax call to pull the filters from session.  The only caveat is that the ajax call must have the cache:false setting.